# create a new dataframe based on given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks like this:

| user id | observation |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 2 |
| 25 | 3 |
| 25 | 2 |
| 23 | 1 |
| 23 | 3 |

the desired outcome is:

| user id | observation | retention |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 7 | 3 |
| 23 | 4 | 2 |

I want to keep the user id column with unique ids and have another column showing how many times this id has appeared in the dataset summing up the observation column values.

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method and chain [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method to it:

```
outputdf=df.groupby('user id',as_index=False).agg(observation=('observation','sum'),retention=('observation','count'))
```

Now if you print `outputdf` you will get your desired output:

```
     user id    observation     retention
0       23          4               2
1       25          7               3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `group by`:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'user id': [25,25,25,33,33], 'observation': [2,3,2,1,3]}

# get the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_new = df.groupby('user id').agg({"sum", "count"}).reset_index()

# rename the columns as you desire
df_new.columns = ['user id', 'observation', 'retention']
df_new
```

Output:
[image]